# How can you use the Serialization and Deserialization macros on things you don't define?

Tags: rust, macros, user-defined-functions, serde

[Rust provides a `Serialize` and `Deserialize` macro](https://serde.rs/derive.html) which are applied by decorating the struct you're defining with `#[derive(Serialize)]` and `#[derive(Deserialize)]`. How do I apply these macros if I'm not defining the struct? Like let's say I have,

```
use foo::Bar;
```

And `Bar` is a struct. How can I make it such that the Bar struct can be serialized and deserialized from within Actix? You can't apply the Serialize macro to use statements or you'll get,

```
error[E0774]: `derive` may only be applied to structs, enums and unions
```

Comment: Do these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279642/how-can-i-implement-serde-for-a-type-that-i-dont-own-and-have-it-support-compou https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982831/can-one-implement-derive-serialize-on-an-enum-without-deriveserialize

Comment: The docs have a section called ["Derive for remote crate"](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html)